# Calculating hashrate from stratum messages

Tags: mining-pools, stratum

Interested in validating algorithm for calculating hashrate from stratum messages.

From my understanding following data is needed:
`start_time` , time when miner started calculating
`end_time`, time when share from miner was found
`difficulty`, set by the mining pool

Formula for calculating hashrate(found online) is:
`hashrate = difficulty * 2**32 / (end_time - start_time)`

Example:
`difficulty` is `131072` from `{"id":null,"method":"mining.set_difficulty","params":[131072]}`
`(end_time - start_time)` is `8.844114780426025` from one real test example

Calculation:
`131072 * 2**32 / 8.844114780426025`
`131072 * 4294967296 / 8.844114780426025`
`562949953421312 / 8.844114780426025`
Hashrate: `63652492917351.58`  or  around `63 Th/s`

Questions:

1. Is this correct ?
2. What is 2**32 ? (suspect that it is connected to nonce in block header)

Answer (score 0):

After 2 months, I know more.

Formula is correct for calculating hashrate of one share.